# Find all users who rated all the movies rated by a specific user

Tags: mysql, relational-division

So we have the following relational schema:

```
users(user_id, ..)
movies(movie_id, ..)
ratings(user_id, movie_id, rate)
```

So, we want to find all the users who have rated all the movies which are rated by a specific user '1234'

In other words, if user '1234' has rated movies 1, 2, 3, and 4, we want the user ID of all others who have also rated movies 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: Do you want to exclude users that has also rated movie 5, i.e. a user who rated movie 1,2,3,4 and 5? This type of query is known as `relational division`

Comment: Are you looking for other users who rated _all_ of those movies, _at least one_ or those movies, or, as Lennart asked, _exactly the same_ (and only those) same movies?

Answer (score 1):

This will not suffer from duplicate votes

```
SELECT user_id
FROM ratings 
WHERE movie_id IN (SELECT movie_id FROM ratings WHERE user_id = '1234') AND user_id <> '1234'
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING count(DISTINCT movie_id) = (SELECT count(DISTINCT movie_id) FROM ratings WHERE user_id = '1234')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select
     ratings.user_id
from ratings 
join movies on movies.movie_id = ratings.movie_id
join ratings l on l.movie_id = movies.movie_id and l.user_id = '1234'
cross join (
    select count(*) as num
    from ratings 
    where raings.user_id  = '1234'
) c
group by ratings.user_id
having count(*) = c.num
```